# Friendly URLs EasyPHP

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, yii, easyphp

I'm trying to configure friendly URLs on my site, and get following error in my Apache error.log:

> [Tue Mar 20 18:41:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script 'C:/EasyPHP/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat

I access my site like this: http://localhost/mysite

Site files are here: d:\Sites\php\projects\mysite\public_html\

My .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

I'm using EasyPHP 5.3.9 and Yii framework.
I've also uncommented this line in httpd.conf:

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with RewriteRule, it has to do with your EasyPhp installation. Just make sure that the website is properly configured (check for the vhosts configuration or maybe if there's only one site, the `httpd.conf` configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Check the /protected/config/main.php file in the yii project and uncommnet the url manager. Here's some help -> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.url